# Undefined index in controller (CakePhp)

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code, which select product from table "products" based on the id.

```
public function p_details(){
$productIdNum = $this->params['detailID'];

        //$this->Product->read(null, $productIdNum);

        if(Validation::naturalNumber($productIdNum) == true){
            $itemById = $this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' =>
            array('Product.id' => $productIdNum)));

            if(count($itemById) > 0){
                $this->set('itemDetails', $itemById['Product']['id']);
            }
        }

    }
```

But when I try to print the variable "$itemDetails" in the view, 
like `<?php echo $itemDetails['Product']['name']; ?>`
it's giving me this error: 
Undefined index: Product. If I change it to this
like `<?php echo $itemDetails['name']; ?>`
It's still give me the same error: Undefined index: name.
I can't get to figure this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Next time you get index not found errors, you can do a `debug($array);` in your view to see what your array actually contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is that with `$this->set('itemDetails', $itemById['Product']['id']);` you assign an id, not an array, to the `itemDetails` variable. Change it to `$this->set('itemDetails', $itemById);`, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I later noticed that as well, though it took me almost an hour to figure it out :) Thanks anyway for your reply